# SQL in Visual studio issues with results

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

NEW info

After some careful thought I have come to the conclusion I'm a bit hard of thinking!

The Linq to SQL below was correct, but I was asking the impossible. I was asking for records that did not exist. By asking for people not on vacation I was assuming that they were allocated to 'something' on that day, but this is not always true. If they have not been allocated to vacation there is no record to find in the Date_Table. If I allocate them to 'not on vacation' say, then the query works. This is OK in testing, but not in the real world.

The question I should of asked was

How do you find these records using VB.Net

All persons in the Person_Table, but excluded if they have a record TODAY in the connected Date_table showing they are on "Vacation"

Any thoughts?

Peter

Good day everyone - I hope this is a simple question! - I have the following query written VB.

I have two tables, one called person_data_table that holds all the names (and their teams), and one called date_table that holds all the data. I pass in a team name from the client at the front end and I want to find the following

All the people that are on the team, but NOT anyone that is on vacation on that day. (date_table.allocated). I can find all the team members, and I can find all the people on vacation on that day, but I can't seem to work out a way of finding the team members but excluding the vacation people. Hope that makes sense, please leave a message if not, and I will try to explain further.

I tried this where clause below and that returned only the people on holiday that were on vacation - I need the exact opposite, I want to exclude them, and see everyone else

```vb
Where Person_data_Table.MK = Date_Table.FK And
      Date_Table.Allocated = "Vacation" And
      Date_Table.Date = Today And
      Person_data_Table.Team Like data_type_requested_variable + "*"
```

The code below does not return any records at all.

Any help gratefully received, please keep it in VB, the C# syntax does not seem to work well for me.

regards

Peter

```vb
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function Save_Data(ByVal data_type_requested_variable As String) As String
    Using db As New MaxDataContext
        Dim selected_type = From Person_data_Table In db.Person_data_tables,
                                 Date_Table In db.Date_Tables
                            Where Person_data_Table.MK = Date_Table.FK And
                                  Date_Table.Allocated <> "Vacation" And
                                  (Date_Table.Date = Today And
                                   Person_data_Table.Team Like data_type_requested_variable + "*")
                            Select Person_data_Table.First_Name,
                                   Person_data_Table.Type,
                                   Person_data_Table.Fri_Avail,
                                   Person_data_Table.Sat_Avail

        Dim Hidden_results_grid As New GridView

        Hidden_results_grid.DataSource = selected_type
        Hidden_results_grid.DataBind()
```

Comment: If you want the opposite of a condition then you need to use a `Not` operator, or perhaps a `<>` instead of an `=`.

Comment: By the way, there's no SQL there. That's a LINQ query. Presumably LINQ to Entities, if you're using Entity Framework, or maybe LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Many thanks, your right about Linq to SQL. As for the not <> operator, I tried that, as you can see above, trouble is that did not returned any records at all.

Comment: Isn't the equivalent of the SQL `c LIKE 'xyz%'` in LINQ: `c.StartsWith('xyz')`? So you would have `Person_data_Table.Team.StartsWith(data_type_requested_variable)`. Which doesn't explain why the first query as shown worked.

Comment: Not entirely sure Andrew, but I can confirm this does work. It finds any team name that is "like" the one that I pass it. I have used this like operator quite a lot is Visual Studio 2017, I think we maybe just have to accept that element works and look beyond it to the core issue, that being how the hell do I not see people on vacation in my returned results set. Thanks Peter

Comment: @PeterW What changed that you had to put parentheses around `Date_Table.Date = Today And Person_data_Table.Team Like data_type_requested_variable + "*"`? They are not present in the first code snippet.

Comment: Nothing significant. I have been trying various combinations of parenthesis to see if that was the issue. None seems to make a difference to the end result.